# Android 6.0 retrieve the list of required permissions programatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

I would like to retrieve the list of all permissions required by the application (as defined in AndroidManifest.xml). The list should include also permissions that were disabled(or just not enabled) by the user. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the permission API doesn't allow this: you need to know the permission and then you can check the status. Theoretically, you could check all the permissions with checkSelfPermission() but then you would need 3rd return status  sth like PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED_BUT_REQUIRED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query the package manager for this info

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pi = p.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
int[] permissionStatus = pi.requestedPermissionsFlags;
```

for permissions that are granted, you'll have the `int` equals [`REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED)

Comment: It works:)  It covers also permissions disabled by the user. The strange thing is that disabled permissions still have status REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED .